# I am making a roblox game and i need it to save data but it wont

Tags: lua, roblox

> it doesnt give error msgs but it wont save i have API services enabled
> no clue why it isnt working please help!

''' local dataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local gameStore = dataStoreService:GetDataStore("TestDataStore")

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local leaderstat = Instance.new("Folder" , plr)`enter code here`
    leaderstat.Name = "leaderstats"

    local Currency = Instance.new("IntValue" , leaderstat)
    Currency.Name = "Currency"
    Currency.Value = 1

    local CurrencyData

    local success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
        CurrencyData = gameStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId .. "-Currency")
    end)

    if success == true then
        Currency.Value = CurrencyData
    else
        print("Cant recover data because " .. errorMsg)
    end
end)

--Save data when server shut down
game:BindToClose(function()
    for i , plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        local success , errorMsg = pcall(function()
            gameStore:SetAsync(plr.UserId .. "-level" , plr.leaderstats.Currency.Value)
        end)

        if success then
            print("Data Secured")
        else
            print("Error while saving data because " .. errorMsg)
        end
    end
end)

--Save data when somebody leaves
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    for i , plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        local success , errorMsg = pcall(function()
            gameStore:SetAsync(plr.UserId .. "-level" , plr.leaderstats.Currency.Value)
        end)

        if success then
            print("Data Secured")
        else
            print("Error while saving data because " .. errorMsg)
        end
    end
```

end)'''

Comment: Probably too late to answer, but if it isn't, try adding a wait statement of about 5-10 seconds when bindtoclose fires. Sometimes the server closes before PlayerRemoving can fire.

Answer (score -2):

i think you have to write the loading script like this (i haven't stored data in awhile so this may not be it):

```
local success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
    CurrencyData = gameStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId.Currency)
end)
```

Comment: This is not a solution, the first argument of `GetAsync` is the key, generally used as a unique identifier. `UserId`, a number, is not something you can index. Therefore this will error. If you are unsure, I would recommend you to post a comment rather than an answer.